# What does "in a play on" mean?

Tags: meaning

Source: http://news.yahoo.com/russias-night-wolves-ride-motherland-033540813.html

> Likewise its riders come from varied social backgrounds, from car mechanics, to businessmen -- even a few monks.
>   "Everyone is free to join -- except for women. 'No woman no cry'," joked Benish **in a play on** the Bob Marley lyric.
>   "Years ago when it was founded, the club was a kind of symbol of virility, of what it means to be a man."

What does that expression exactly mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reggae musician Bob Marley performed a song entitled "No woman, no cry." The title lyric is commonly assumed to mean that women, and relationships, cause a lot of crying. This seems to be the sense the lyric was taken in here.

However, it is worth noting (perhaps for Bob Marley's sake) that the Jamaican dialect of English sometimes uses the word "no" to mean "don't." In this case the word is pronounced "Nuh." This changes the meaning of the song considerably.

**Edit**: I just noticed that I missed your point entirely. "In a play on" in this case seems to denote that the quote is specifically a reference to the Bob Marley lyric.

Answer (score 2):

*In a play on* means to wrest a phrase from its original meaning to fit different circumstances, usually in a humorous manner.

Answer (score 0):

I believe he could be making reference to the Queen or its code for NO VICTIM NO CRIME referring to trespass, loitering (government yard in trench town) or even smoking joints (Georgie would make the fire light).
He is trying to tell the common man about common law and the inherent rights of every living human being.